# ¿Cómo obtener el nombre de una table desde una tabla en SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

Tengo la duda sobre si se puede obtener el nombre de una tabla desde una consulta de otra table, por ejemplo algo así:

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT nombreTablas FROM tablas);`

Sé que esa consulta no es posible (ya lo intenté), pero mi idea es poder dejar todos los nombres de las tablas en una "tabla maestra" que repita el mismo query para todas las tablas, y poder insertar información en cada una de esta forma. ¿Es posible?

Comment: Esto que queres hacer, suena muy pero muy raro, sobre todo en sqlite.. podrias explicar porque querrias hacer algo asi con una base que es para cosas chiquitas?

Comment: resulta que tengo una tabla que alimenta a otras 20 pero son todas iguales pero necesito según sea el nombre insertar una info u otra, el query que me gustaría lograr es:

INSERT INTO (SELECT nombreTablas FROM tablas) (variable1) VALUES (SELECT tablaGeneral.dato1 FROM tablaGeneral WHERE tablaGeneral.ruta LIKE (SELECT nombreTablas FROM tablas);

Answer (score 1):

Resulta que sqlite tiene una tabla escondida en cada base de datos (cada archivo) que se llama sqlite_master.

La misma, segun la [documentación](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#storage_of_the_sql_database_schema), tiene la siguiente estructura.

```
CREATE TABLE sqlite_master(
  type text,
  name text,
  tbl_name text,
  rootpage integer,
  sql text
);
```

Ahora, justamente lo que vos queres hacer figura en la pagina de [faq del manual](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html), en el punto 7

Ahi dice que para obtener el nombre de las tablas, podes hacer:

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type='table'
ORDER BY name;
```

Y eso te va a devolver el nombre de todas las tablas de tu base.

Comment: si, pero quiero usar, en la misma consulta, ese valor como nombre de la tabla de la cuál quiero recuperar los datos, ejemplo: SELECT * FROM (SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'; y obtener los datos de todas las tablas

Answer (score 1):

Respuesta corta: Si Es posible:

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type='table';
```

Esto te arrojará una tabla con todas las tablas. Lo que en en MySql sería

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='nombreDB'
```

Comment: como dije más arriba, yo quiero realizar una consulta en base a esa consulta, es decir obtener los datos de las tablas sin tener que poner el nombre de las tablas

Comment: Es lo mismo, ¿Lo quieres hacer  directamente desde el IDE de Sqlite o desde un lenguaje de programación?

Comment: Si yo aplico: SELECT * FROM (SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'); me arroja los nombrs de las tablas y no el contenido de dichas tablas, o interpreté mal lo que me dijiste

Comment: Por eso te preguntaba si lo quieres hacer directo en el IDE de Sqlite o en algún lenguaje. Por que si es en un lenguaje solo debes hacer un "foreach resultado Select..."